# An issue with ehynds jquery-multiselect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, knockout-2.0, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a fiddle showing this issue here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jrwarwick/XEg4K/

Please ignore 
a) the menu's not initially hiding and appearing in the wrong place issue, that is not pertinent.
b) the multiselect not working on that fiddle for some unknown reason.

THE ISSUE:
When the multiselect component is repeated like this I get the problem.
If you click the checkbox/radiobutton of a lower down multiselect it works as expected.
BUT if you click the label instead of the checkbox/radio then the first multiselect receives the event instead of the one that was open, and the first multiselect overwrites its value with the corresponding indexed value of the actual clicked multiselect option!

Is there a workaround possible for this? Or should I go and place this on Eric Hynds bug tracker?

Thanks.

CODE:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" style="position: relative">
<div class="control-group">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 10px;">Characteristics</h4>
    <div id="characterisitics" data-bind="with: d">
        <div data-bind="foreach: Rows" class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" data-bind="text: name"></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="label" for="ddlContent" style="min-width: 60px; text-align: right" data-bind="text: typename"></label>
                <select id="ddlContent" class="input-medium" data-bind="multiSelectCheck:true, minWidth: 150, multiple: typename=='List', selectedOptions: values, header: false, options: TypeContent, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'cvalue'" multiple="multiple">
               </select>
                <input type="text" class="input-large" maxlength="50" data-bind="value: $parent['type' + location]" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().multiselectOptions) || {};

        // pass the original options to the similar widget option
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().optionsCaption)) {
            multiselectOptions.noneSelectedText = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().optionsCaption);
        }
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().header) === false) {
            multiselectOptions.header = false;
        }
        multiselectOptions.multiple = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().multiple);
        multiselectOptions.minWidth = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().minWidth);
        allBindingsAccessor().optionsCaption = '';

        $(element).multiselect(multiselectOptions);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).multiselect("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
        var multiselectOptions = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().multiSelectCheck);
        // remove this and use the widget's 

        // pass the original options to the similar widget option

        allBindingsAccessor().optionsCaption = '';

        ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(element).multiselect("refresh");
        }, 0);

    }

};

var data = { "d": {
    "type1": ko.observable(),
    "type2": ko.observable(),
    "type3": ko.observable(),
    "Rows": [
      {
        "id": 26,
        "catid": 24,
        "name": "Processor Type",
        "location": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "typename": "Text",
        "TypeContent": [
          {
            "id": 195,
            "name": "Celeron",
            "cvalue": "Celeron",
            "location": 7,
            "name_fixed": "celeron laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 196,
            "name": "Athlon",
            "cvalue": "Athlon",
            "location": 8,
            "name_fixed": "athlon laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 599,
            "name": "Centrino",
            "cvalue": "Centrino",
            "location": 9,
            "name_fixed": "centrino laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 772,
            "name": "PowerPC G4",
            "cvalue": "PowerPC G4",
            "location": 10,
            "name_fixed": "powerpc g4 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 969,
            "name": "Sempron",
            "cvalue": "Sempron",
            "location": 11,
            "name_fixed": "sempron laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 970,
            "name": "Turion 64",
            "cvalue": "Turion 64",
            "location": 12,
            "name_fixed": "turion 64 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 2714,
            "name": "Intel Dual Core",
            "cvalue": "Intel Dual Core",
            "location": 13,
            "name_fixed": "intel dual core laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 3472,
            "name": "Intel Core Duo",
            "cvalue": "Intel Core Duo",
            "location": 14,
            "name_fixed": "intel core duo laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 3710,
            "name": "C7 M",
            "cvalue": "C7 M",
            "location": 15,
            "name_fixed": "c7 m laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 3821,
            "name": "Intel Core 2 Duo",
            "cvalue": "Intel Core 2 Duo",
            "location": 16,
            "name_fixed": "intel core 2 duo laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 3822,
            "name": "Intel Quad Core",
            "cvalue": "Intel Quad Core",
            "location": 17,
            "name_fixed": "intel quad core laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 3823,
            "name": "Intel Core 2 Quad",
            "cvalue": "Intel Core 2 Quad",
            "location": 19,
            "name_fixed": "intel core 2 quad laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 4172,
            "name": "Intel Atom",
            "cvalue": "Intel Atom",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "intel atom laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5718,
            "name": "Intel Core i5",
            "cvalue": "Intel Core i5",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "intel core i5 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5719,
            "name": "Intel Core i7",
            "cvalue": "Intel Core i7",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "intel core i7 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5822,
            "name": "Intel Core i3",
            "cvalue": "Intel Core i3",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "intel core i3 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5885,
            "name": "Intel Pentium",
            "cvalue": "Intel Pentium",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "intel pentium laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5924,
            "name": "AMD Phenom",
            "cvalue": "AMD Phenom",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd phenom laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5933,
            "name": "Intel Core Solo",
            "cvalue": "Intel Core Solo",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "intel core solo laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5934,
            "name": "Dual Core II",
            "cvalue": "Dual Core II",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "dual core ii laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5942,
            "name": "AMD V Series",
            "cvalue": "AMD V Series",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd v series laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5943,
            "name": "Athlon II Neo",
            "cvalue": "Athlon II Neo",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "athlon ii neo laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 5967,
            "name": "Celeron 900",
            "cvalue": "Celeron 900",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "celeron 900 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6018,
            "name": "Atom Dual Core",
            "cvalue": "Atom Dual Core",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "atom dual core laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6059,
            "name": "AMD E350",
            "cvalue": "AMD E350",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd e350 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6161,
            "name": "AMD P340",
            "cvalue": "AMD P340",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd p340 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6567,
            "name": "AMD C50",
            "cvalue": "AMD C50",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd c50 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6589,
            "name": "AMD Turion",
            "cvalue": "AMD Turion",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd turion laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6605,
            "name": "AMD Dual-Core",
            "cvalue": "AMD Dual-Core",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd dual core laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6827,
            "name": "AMD E-450",
            "cvalue": "AMD E-450",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd e 450 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6828,
            "name": "AMD A-Series",
            "cvalue": "AMD A-Series",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd a series laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6829,
            "name": "AMD E-240",
            "cvalue": "AMD E-240",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd e 240 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6903,
            "name": "AMD E2",
            "cvalue": "AMD E2",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd e2 laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6905,
            "name": "AMD C-Series",
            "cvalue": "AMD C-Series",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd c series laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          },
          {
            "id": 6906,
            "name": "AMD E-Series",
            "cvalue": "AMD E-Series",
            "location": 20,
            "name_fixed": "amd e series laptops",
            "typeid": 26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 493,
        "catid": 24,
        "name": "Weight",
        "location": 2,
        "type": 2,
        "typename": "Range",
        "TypeContent": [
          {
            "id": 4755,
            "name": "1-2 kg",
            "cvalue": "1-2",
            "location": 1,
            "name_fixed": "1 2 kg laptops",
            "typeid": 493
          },
          {
            "id": 4756,
            "name": "2-3 kg",
            "cvalue": "2-3",
            "location": 2,
            "name_fixed": "2 3 kg laptops",
            "typeid": 493
          },
          {
            "id": 4757,
            "name": "3-4 kg",
            "cvalue": "3-4",
            "location": 3,
            "name_fixed": "3 4 kg laptops",
            "typeid": 493
          },
          {
            "id": 4758,
            "name": "4-5 kg",
            "cvalue": "4-5",
            "location": 4,
            "name_fixed": "4 5 kg laptops",
            "typeid": 493
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 704,
        "catid": 24,
        "name": "Display Resolution",
        "location": 3,
        "type": 3,
        "typename": "List",
        "TypeContent": [
          {
            "id": 6982,
            "name": "2880x1800",
            "cvalue": "2880x1800",
            "location": 1,
            "name_fixed": "2880x1800 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6981,
            "name": "2560x1600",
            "cvalue": "2560x1600",
            "location": 2,
            "name_fixed": "2560x1600 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6973,
            "name": "1920x1080",
            "cvalue": "1920x1080",
            "location": 2,
            "name_fixed": "1920x1080 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6974,
            "name": "1680x1080",
            "cvalue": "1680x1080",
            "location": 2,
            "name_fixed": "1680x1080 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6975,
            "name": "1600x900",
            "cvalue": "1600x900",
            "location": 3,
            "name_fixed": "1600x900 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6976,
            "name": "1440x900",
            "cvalue": "1440x900",
            "location": 4,
            "name_fixed": "1440x900 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6977,
            "name": "1366x768",
            "cvalue": "1366x768",
            "location": 5,
            "name_fixed": "1366x768 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6978,
            "name": "1280x1024",
            "cvalue": "1280x1024",
            "location": 6,
            "name_fixed": "1280x1024 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6979,
            "name": "1280x800",
            "cvalue": "1280x800",
            "location": 7,
            "name_fixed": "1280x800 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6980,
            "name": "1280x720",
            "cvalue": "1280x720",
            "location": 8,
            "name_fixed": "1280x720 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          },
          {
            "id": 6986,
            "name": "1024x600",
            "cvalue": "1024x600",
            "location": 9,
            "name_fixed": "1024x600 laptops",
            "typeid": 704
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.d.Rows, function (o, i) {
    o.values = ko.observableArray((data.d['type' + o.location]() + '').replace(', ', ',').split(','));
    o.values.subscribe(function () { data.d['type' + this.location](this.values().join(',')) }, o);
});

ko.applyBindings(data);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise the problem now.

Each select box needed a unique id.

That sorted it out.